# Updated Design Tokens with VSCode and SLDS Validator

Tags: slds, vs-code

Recently, I am getting slds validation errors in VS Code for 'presumably' updated design tokens for the aura component .cmp file.  It is complaining that: `slds-m-bottom_medium` should be updated to `slds-var-m-bottom_medium` however, when I go to SLDS to confirm if this change is in fact a new change to SLDS, I am seeing no such change.  THis ins't only for margins, but padding too

Has anyone experienced this issue, and outside of just turning off SLDS Validtor, are there any workarounds.  I can't imagine that they are actually changing the class to contain `var` but, I do not know this either.

Comment: in what type of file are you getting these errors/warning? .js ? .css ? .html ?

Comment: the aura.cmp file

Comment: Happens on the LWC HTML file as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some standard tokens now have variable token alternatives so that they are responsive to display density.

References:
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/margin/#Variable-Density-Classes

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/padding/#Variable-Density-Classes

Comment: Thank you!  I looked around but I guess not hard enough.